# HTML link issue

Tags: html

I'm attempting to learn some **HTML** on my own and I'm starting out with some very basic formatting and linking:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1> First Heading </h1>
    <a href = “http://www.stackoverflow.com” target=“_blank”>TEST LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I saved the file as `.html` and it opens correctly in any browser like I would expect, but when attempting to click the link, the browser displays a '*website not found*' message. The URL shows the directory to the folder on my computer where I created the `HTML` document followed by http://www.stackoverflow.com.

I feel like this is a formatting issue but I have tried all kinds of variations of the notation. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

Thanks for the help guys! I think **TextEdit** is just the source of the problem. I wrote a new `HTML` file in **VIM** and everything is working perfectly.

Comment: you are using wrong quotes. Change `“` to `"`

Comment: you using wrong double quotes. “” = ""

Comment: There is a reason why it is recommended not to write html code in a normal texteditor. Use textwrangler (mac), notepad++(windows), or sublime/kate/vim(linux)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo because you used wrong quotes.

Change this:

```
<a href = “http://www.stackoverflow.com” target=“_blank”>TEST LINK</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your quotes. You're using `“` instead of `"`

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kjqLbdq1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes. `”` should be `"`. When copying/pasting code, always make sure to do by pasting the value. Here's the code with correct quotes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1> First Heading </h1>
    <a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo with your `"`. Just re-type them:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `”`. Instead, use the double quote sign (`"`) for all links and attributes.

Check the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1> First Heading </h1>
    <a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are wrong for both the href attribute and the target attribute.

Try using " " like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link to Google</a>
```

You can use both single quotes ' ' and double quotes " " for the attribute values, but it is recommended that you use double.